# Submersibles and Submarines

Tags: talmud-gemara

Is there any place in Talmud Bavli or the Rishonim where it speaks of an individual going under water using a submarine or submersible type vessel or tool?

Comment: Yonah was in the first submarine!

Comment: https://www.hellenicaworld.com/Greece/Technology/en/UnderWater.html

Comment: The first submersible vehicle was built by Cornelis Drebbel in 1620. What makes you think they've had submarines during the time of the rishonim? In Bava Kamma 91a, it relates that Rabbi Akiva said "you plunged into the mighty waters". The word צוֹלֶֽלֶת is used and could translate as a submarine (https://www.sefaria.org/Klein_Dictionary,_%D7%A6%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9C%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%AA.1), but again, hard to believe that they've had submarines back then.

Comment: I remember very vaguely that you can read  Ramban as referring to the Teiva as a submersible